# Summing over quantum states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, identical-particles, density-of-states

> For a system of $N$ identical particles we deal in quantum mechanics with wave functions $\langle \{\mathbf{r}_i \} \mid \Psi \rangle=\Psi(\mathbf{r}_1,\dots,\mathbf{r}_N)$ from which determine the probabilities of the particles being at positions $\{\mathbf{r}_1,\dots,\mathbf{r}_N \}$,
>   $$\langle \Psi \mid \Psi \rangle=\langle \Psi \mid \sum_{\mathbf{r}_i}\mid \{\mathbf{r}_i \}  \rangle\langle \{\mathbf{r}_i \} \mid \Psi \rangle=\sum_{\mathbf{r}_i}|\Psi(\mathbf{r}_1,\dots,\mathbf{r}_N)|^2=1$$
>   where $\displaystyle \sum_{\mathbf{r}_i} = \int \prod_{i=1}^Nd^3r_i$.

I cannot see why $\displaystyle \sum_{\mathbf{r}_i} = \int \prod_{i=1}^Nd^3r_i$ holds. Surely we should integrate over the momentum as well? I think this because earlier in my notes it states that:

> All microstates should in principle be included in the partition sum over states irrespective of the macroscopic properties of the system

Also why dont we have a factor of $\frac{1}{N!}$ to represent the indistinguishability of particles?

Comment: That has nothing to do with statistical mechanics. $\sum_r \langle \vec r\vert \psi \rangle$ is always $\int \mathrm{d}^3 r \psi(r)$ in the position representation. How would you even integrate $\psi$ over momenta if it doesn't *depend* on momenta?

Comment: Apologies, this is from my statistical mechanics course. See I would have thought we would have to integrate over mometum anyway, just the integrand wouldnt effect the integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think $\displaystyle\sum_{\mathbf{r}_i}=\int\prod_{i=1}^Nd^3r_i$ here is just a notation of your teacher, you don't need to be fussy about it.

For the "integrate over the momentum", I don't get your point since I'm not sure if particles' momenta are quantum numbers describing this many-body state.

And to answer the question about the factor $\dfrac{1}{N!}$, you can refer to my answer here for another question
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/462446/223370